# Get statuses that changed from 0->1->0 but not 0->1->2->1->0 sql

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I am working on retrieving status changes from a DB where the table is something like

| ID | Old_value | new_value | old_value_date | new_value_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 2021-12-04 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 2021-12-04 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2021-12-04 00:00:00 | 2021-12-05 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2021-12-05 00:00:00 | 2021-12-06 00:00:00 |

From this table I need the IDs which have gone from 0 to 1 and back to 0 but not the Ids which have gone from 0 to 1 to 2 and then back to 1 then 0.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: 'something like' or actually like?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING sum(old_value = 0 AND new_value = 1) > 0
   AND sum(old_value = 1 AND new_value = 0) > 0
   AND sum(old_value = 1 AND new_value = 2) = 0
   AND sum(old_value = 2 AND new_value = 1) = 0
```